# how get content of div via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to get content of div named 'topage' , i did this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var topagge = document.getElementsByClassName("topage");
             console.log(topagge);

         </script>
```

in the console it shows like this :

HTMLCollection[1]
    0: span.topage
         ...
         innerText:"mycontentofdiv"
    length: 1
    **proto**: HTMLCollection

i want to get the innerText value , i try this code :

```
 console.log(topagge.innerText);
```

but in the console it's undefined

please how can i get content of this collection html object ( using the attribut 0 : span.topage wich contain the innerText.

Comment: have you tried `topagge.innerHtml`?

Comment: Also check because you have topagge and topage. As said innerHTML is the way to go.

Comment: even with innerHtml it's stil undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the HTML docuemnt is fully loaded. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var topagge = document.getElementsByClassName("topage");
    console.log(topagge);
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

window.getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements; then, following  code will get HTML content of first element:

```
topagge[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: yes this is the solution , the problem of undefined is that HTML dosnt complet rendring , but with window.onload it work :) ,

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var topagge =document.getElementsByClassName("topage")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(topagge);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This function getElementsByClassName return Collection or return an array of all elements of this class name so you should change your code to be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var topagge = document.getElementsByClassName("topage")[0];
    console.log(topagge.textContent); // or topagge.innerHTML;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of a div, use .innerHTML.

document.getElementByClassName is not supported in IE. Can you assign the div an ID, and use document.getElementById instead?

Comment: i'm using chrome, and even changing by an id it didnt work

Comment: document.getElementById is supported by all browsers that run JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
console.log(topagge.innerHTML)
```