# Get content of DIV using javascript, .innerHTML not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, innerhtml

I currently have a jQuery drag and drop, and want to insert the final results in a database. I want to use Javascript to get the values, but I keep getting the result 'NULL', instead of the actual content (generated by PHP/MySQL)

This is my JavaScript

```
function getValue() {
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
try{

  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){

  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e) {

     try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }catch (e){

        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser broke!");
        return false;
     }
  }
  }

var left1 = document.getElementById('left1').getAttribute('value');
var left2 = document.getElementById("left2").getAttribute('value'); 
var left3 = document.getElementById("left3").getAttribute('value');

 var queryString = "?left1=" + left1 ;
 queryString +=  "&left2=" + left2 + "&left3=" + left3;
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/ff/public_html/drag_and_drop.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

PHP Code:

```
$dinner1 = $_GET['dinner1'];
$dinner2 = $_GET['dinner2'];
$dinner3 = $_GET['dinner3'];

$query2 = "INSERT INTO weekly_print (dinner1, dinner2, dinner3) VALUES ('".$dinner1."','".$dinner2."','".$dinner3."')";
            $result2 = mysql_query ($query2) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
            if (@mysql_num_rows($result2) != 0) {
                echo 'Success!!';

        }
}
```

I have tried using it without the `getAttrubute('value');`, however I kept getting `[object HTMLDivElement]` as a result.

These are similar questions, but they have not worked for me at all.

[how get content of div via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395800/how-get-content-of-div-via-javascript)
[Get content of a DIV using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647216/get-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)
[JavaScript innerHTML not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826756/javascript-innerhtml-not-working)

When using innerHTML I get the result '[object HTMLDivElement]'.

I know I need to change over to mysqli instead of mysql, its on a testing server at the moment, so please ignore that.

My HTML:

```
<div class="column" id="left1" style="border: 2px solid #a13f80;"></div>
<div class="column" id="left2" style="border: 2px solid #a13f80;"></div>
<div class="column" id="left3" style="border: 2px solid #a13f80;"></div>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Div elements don't have values. Your div elements don't have value attributes (which would be invalid anyway) and they don't have any content. What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to get values instead of attibutes:
`document.getElementById('left1').value;`

Replace your code with :

```
var left1 = document.getElementById('left1').value;
var left2 = document.getElementById("left2").value; 
var left3 = document.getElementById("left3").value;
```

And Convert your div structure to input fields as getting values from div and passing it to php is very non-standard method:

```
<input class="column" id="left1" style="border: 2px solid #a13f80;" />
<input class="column" id="left2" style="border: 2px solid #a13f80;" />
<input class="column" id="left3" style="border: 2px solid #a13f80;" />
```

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, but my result was [object HTMLDivElement]?

Comment: Oh you dont have any inputs

Comment: with document.getElemebetByID() you dont need inputs? Or am i going about this the wrong way?

Comment: nothing to do with getElementByID - but only inputs have a .value

Comment: Can you suggest how i can improve this? @Vicky Gonsalves

Comment: @VickyGonsalves I cant change the divs to input, my jquery will not work that way. There has to be a way to get the value of the DIV without an input method.? See my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjbpXX

Comment: I can only wish Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Your divs are empty, thats why innerHTML is not working

PS: Can't comment to little points

Comment: *innerText* is non–standard and not supported by all browsers in use. This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: as previously mentioned var left1 = document.getElementById('left1').value; is not working, i get the result  [object HTMLDivElement].

Comment: @Denni007 They are not empty, they are generated by PHP as they come out of a database.

Comment: Oh, I can comment my own answer, that's interesting. Sorry but I need 50 reputation vor comments.

Comment: @Fushy How does the HTML looks like after fill? Can you show the problem with something like codepen?

Comment: @Denni007 Here is the link to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjbpXX
The aim is to drag and drop the content into the boxes, and then insert to mysql (Can't do that on codepen, but you get what i am trying to do)

Comment: @Denni007 I solved my issue, my AJAX was not passing the javascript variable to php correctly. I solved it by changing my ajax to: $.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:8888/ff/public_html/drag_and_drop.php',
     data: {x: left1},
     type: 'GET'
  });

Comment: Nice to see, that you solved your issue. But you must learn to reduce your problems to a minimum, show the fork http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmbowX and you see innerHTML is nice working on a div ;)

Answer (score -1):

USe `innerText` or `textContent` attribute to get div text.

```
left1div = document.getElementById('left1');
var left1divval = left1div.textContent || left1div.innerText;   
alert(left1divval);
```

[See Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x8d686s6/)

Comment: I have changed it to this, but now its "undefined"?

Comment: check the working example... its working fine. there is some other error in your code.